# How to find css link from html page

Tags: php, css, regex, tags

I have php regex to find  tag and extract css address from html page

```
'/<link.*?href\s*=\s*["\']([^"\']+)[^>]*>.*?\/>/i'
```

but it doesn't work good.can you help me to modify this code?

Comment: You shouldn't use regular expressions to parse HTML. Use the DOM instead.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
'/<link .*?(href=[\'|"](.*)?[\'|"]|\/?\>)/i'
```

Then you can acces the link with `$2`

Answer (score 0):

Regex to find hrefs of all stylesheets can be a tricky task. You should consider using some PHP HTML parser to get this information.

You can read **[this article](http://davidwalsh.name/php-notifications)** to get more information and then try this code.

```
// Retrieve all links and print their HREFs
foreach($html->find('link') as $e)
    echo $e->href . '<br>';

// Retrieve all script tags and print their SRCs
foreach($html->find('script') as $e)
    echo $e->src . '<br>';
```

**PS:** Remember, your script tag may not contain a src then it will print empty string.

Comment: Thank's.I want use this code for search <script> tag but it shows "<br><br><br><br><br>" how change it?

Comment: @user3001854 Added code for script tag and do read PS

Comment: @user3001854 You can read the article mentioned in answer to get details..That is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Not that this is better than the other answer, however just in case you want to see it, I've altered your regex such that it should work as intended:

```
'/<link.*?href\s*=\s*["\']([^"\']+?)[\'"]/i'
```